# Find sequence of specific binary combination

Tags: sequences-and-series, linear-programming, binary

We have a set $S_n$ containing $n$ binary values, lets say $S_6$ = [0,0,1,1,0,1].

I want to make sure that only one consecutive 0 may occur between the 1's.

$P_6$ = [1,0,1,1,0,1] Allowed.

$Q_6$ = [1,1,0,0,0,0] Allowed.

$U_6$ = [1,1,0,0,0,1] Not allowed.

The problem can be divided into two parts:

1. Look for occurrence of sequence [1,0,0].
2. If found, make sure that the sum of all the consecutive elements adds up to 0.

**How do you express this in mathematical terms?**

Comment: That approach would forbid your second example $Q_6$.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "sum of all the consecutive elements".  Which elements are consecutive? Can you give an example?

Comment: @MatthewConroy The sum of all the consecutive elements means the sum of the rest of the elements as of the elements following [1,0,0].

In $Q_6$ = [1,1,0,0,**0,0**] this means the last two elements. Since these two elements sum up to 0, we can be sure that there are none following occurrences of 1.

Comment: @ErwinKalvelagen Are you sure? Look at the explanation I am giving to MatthewConroy.